# How to check if a date string already has two forward slashes in it?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need your help,

Is there a way to code a javascript function that would regex and test a string or using any other means to check if a date string already has the two forward slashes in it? ie. dd/mm/yyyy

```
regex('04/07/2014') { return true }
```

Thanks in advance for all your help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
/\/.*\//.test("04/07/2014")
```

Comment: /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/ ?

Comment: @mplungjan, Well, you could use `/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/` to check if it's date-like, but the OP asked to check for two slashes.

Comment: which will match //, no?

Comment: @mplungjan, Yes, it will match `//` as requested.

Comment: which is what OP thinks he wants :)

Comment: @mplungjan, If he wants to check if he has a date (even though he said he had a date), he can use the pattern in the second comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/([^/]*\/){2}/
```

to check if input has at least 2 forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

use `/\/.*\//.test( str )` it returns true if `str` has two forward slashes in it.